# Redis on Symfony2 OS X Yosemite not working

Tags: php, symfony, redis, osx-yosemite

I have got a problem with redis on Symfony2 on OS X Yosemite.
I have installed SncRedisBundle and install redis and php55-redis with brew.
I start the redis server with `redis-server`.

But my symfony application returns:

```
500: Attempted to load class "Redis" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Usually, I work on ubuntu with my symfony project and everything work perfectly but I want to install my project also on my mac, but I doesn't understand why it's not working on the mac.

Comment: What is output of `get_include_path();`?

Comment: Output of `get_include_path();` is only `.:`

Comment: @Bostak If you just moved your project to Mac perhaps a `composer update` (if you have not done it). It seems to me that the bundle was not registered correctly by the autoloader.

Comment: I have already run `composer install` but when I try to run `composer update` I have this error `[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                        
  The .git directory is missing from /var/www/foot2018/vendor/snc/redis-bundle/Snc/RedisBundle, see https://getcomposer.org/commit-deps fo  
  r more information `